# How many buttons at once?

Tags: gpio

I own Raspberry Pi 2 B and I wanted to create something like Novation's Launchpad. How many buttons can I connect through GPIO at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without add-ons and using the Pi's gpios 26 (or 28 if you are happy to forgo HAT compatibility).

If you buy something like a [MCP23017](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/electronic-components/misc-ic/mcp23017-16bit-port-expander) (port expander) you can have 100s.  They provide 16 additional gpios each and 8 may be connected to an I2C bus (the I2C bus is Pi pins 3 and 5).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sufficiently familiar with the Pi, but if you have 8 bits out and 8 bits in, and a bunch of signal diodes,  you can implement a software keyboard encoder for a 64-switch matrix...